# Update a nested property with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I Have a class that has a non-primitive property.
I need to update some child property of that property of parent class.

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Abc { get; set; }
    public Childclass Pos { get; set; }
}

public class Childclass
{
     public string Value { get; set; }
}

List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>()

Parent p1 = new Parent();
p1.Pos.Value = "1";
parents.Add(p1);

Parent p2 = new Parent();
p2.Pos.Value = "2";
parents.Add(p2);
```

Now I need to update `Pos` in parents`where Pos.Value == "2"` ?

Comment: But `Pos` property is not an `int` but `Childclass`?

Comment: Did you mean `p1.Pos.Value = "1"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>();

Parent p1 = new Parent();
p1.Pos = new Childclass() { Value = "1" };
parents.Add(p1);

Parent p2 = new Parent();
p2.Pos = new Childclass() { Value = "2" };
parents.Add(p2);
```

If you need to update every items :

```
foreach (Parent parent in parents.Where(e => e.Pos.Value.Equals("2")))
    parent.Pos.Value = "new value";
```

If you need to update the first item only :

```
parents.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Pos.Value.Equals("2")).Pos.Value = "new value";
```

Comment: and if i know that there is only one with Pos.Value == 2, i need always to loop all?

Comment: and if Pos is List<ChildClass>?

Comment: The `ToList` call in the foreach is, i believe, extraneous; it loops over all the data to build the list, then you loop over a new list. Leaving it off allows the construction of an enumerable, and so it is in a sense lazier.

Answer (score 2):

I think,you need like this:

```
parents.Where(l => l.Pos.Value.Equals("2")).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Post.Value="updateValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the value using [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx), which will retrieve the first element matching the predicate:

```
var parent = parents.FirstOrDefault(
                x => x.Pos.Value.Equals("2", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
parent.Pos.Value = "3";
```

If you have alot of lookups, perhaps you'd want to use a `Dictionary<string, Parent>` where the key is some immutable value which doesn't change, if possible:

```
var keyToParent = new Dictionary<string, Parent>
{
    ["Abc"] = p1,
    ["Dfc"] = p2
};

if (!keyToParent.ContainsKey("Abc"))
    return;

var retrievedParent = keyToParent["Abc"];
retrievedParent.Pos.Value = "3";
```